# how to disable background-color input fields

Tags: forms, validation

I am using a form validation with javascript. 
When submitting, the background-color of those input fields which are not valid changes to red color. When filling up this field and typing into another input field, the red background-color of the former field should go away. This is at the moment not the case. It only disappears when submitting again. How can I make this possible that the bg color changes back to normal when typing into another field?

```
// Return true if the input value is not empty
function isNotEmpty(inputId, errorMsg) {
var inputElement = document.getElementById(inputId);
var errorElement = document.getElementById(inputId + "Error");
var inputValue = inputElement.value.trim();
var isValid = (inputValue.length !== 0);  // boolean
showMessage(isValid, inputElement, errorMsg, errorElement);
return isValid;
}

/* If "isValid" is false, print the errorMsg; else, reset to normal display.
* The errorMsg shall be displayed on errorElement if it exists;
*   otherwise via an alert().
*/
function showMessage(isValid, inputElement, errorMsg, errorElement) {
if (!isValid) {
  // Put up error message on errorElement or via alert()
  if (errorElement !== null) {
     errorElement.innerHTML = errorMsg;
  } else {
     alert(errorMsg);
  }
  // Change "class" of inputElement, so that CSS displays differently
  if (inputElement !== null) {
     inputElement.className = "error";
     inputElement.focus();
  }
  } else {
  // Reset to normal display
  if (errorElement !== null) {
     errorElement.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if (inputElement !== null) {
     inputElement.className = "";
  }
  }
 }
```

The form:

```
  <td>Name<span class="red">*</span></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="name" name="firstname"/></td>
  <p id="nameError" class="red">&nbsp;</p>
```

The submit:

```
<input type="submit" value="SEND" id="submit"/>
```

Css:

```
input.error {  /* for the error input text fields */
background-color: #fbc0c0;
}
```

**Update:**
I tried this but it seems not to work:

```
function checkFilled() {
var inputVal = document.querySelectorAll("#offerteFirstname, #offerteLastname, #offertePhone, #offertePoster, #offerteStreet").value;
if (inputVal == "") {
    document.querySelectorAll("#offerteFirstname, #offerteLastname, #offertePhone, #offertePoster, #offerteStreet").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
else{
    document.querySelectorAll("#offerteFirstname, #offerteLastname, #offertePhone, #offertePoster, #offerteStreet").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
}

checkFilled();
```

Answer (score 0):

here example of it

```
<input type="text" id="subEmail" onchange="checkFilled();"/>
```

and now you can JavaScript on input

```
function checkFilled() {
var inputVal = document.getElementById("subEmail").value;
if (inputVal == "") {
    document.getElementById("subEmail").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
else{
    document.getElementById("subEmail").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
}

checkFilled();
```

here working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/14/)

Comment: this works great with one single input id; but I have several input fields with different id's. How can I make it work for all those fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(formElement).on('keyup','input.error', function(){
    if(<values changed>){
        $(this).removeClass('error');
    }
});
```